# Tunebite Platinum and VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, mac

Has anybody managed to get [Tunebite Platinum](http://www.tunebite.com-http.com/tunebite-platinum.html) working with [VMware Fusion 3](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/)? My installation hangs and product struggles with the in-built devices on my iMac. I'm trying to remove the DRM from TV shows I bought in the iTunes store so I can burn them to DVD.

My guest system is Win XP and I'm using OSX 10.5.8.

Answer (score 0):

I would try posting your question in the [Tunebite support forum](http://audials.com/forum/index.php?page=Board&boardID=5). It sounds like, for whatever reason, Tunebite isn't compatible with a virtualized OS. Your best bet would be to post there so the developers of the software can be made aware of the problem, as they are the best suited to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge cutoff in September 2021, Tunebite Platinum is not officially compatible with VMware Fusion 3 or Mac OS X 10.5.8. It's possible that compatibility issues or conflicts with the in-built devices on your iMac are causing the installation to hang. I recommend checking the official support resources for Tunebite Platinum or contacting the support team for further assistance. Alternatively, you can explore other software options that are specifically designed for removing DRM and converting TV shows for DVD burning on a Mac. I recommend [StreamGaGa](https://streamgaga.com/). I've used it for monthes to remove the DRM in videos from many streaming services.